# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: h.json is not a function in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express

I have above error in react. The following code is causing the error. This happens after pressing the submit button in the contact form. Where is the mistake?

ContactForm.js

```
const ContactForm = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const { name, email, subject, business, datetime, launch, message } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      subject: subject.value,
      business: business.value,
      datetime: datetime.value,
      launch: launch.value,
      message: message.value,
    };
    let response = await("https://delightart.co/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };
```

Comment: `response = await("https://delightart.co/send", {` what are you awaiting here? Did you mean `response = await fetch("https://delightart.co/send", {` instead?

Comment: @GabrielChristiansen `response.json` returns promise

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Oh, assuming they're trying to use `fetch` you're right

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added fetch after await. Now I get 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'.  I think that response is not a JSON. How possibly fix it?

Comment: @Gabriel Christiansen How to modify response.json() to async in this case?

Comment: `response.json()` is already async. @evolutionxbox was right. Looks like your endpoint might not be returning json?

Comment: @ragdoll. Test your endpoint using something like Postman. Looks like the `https://delightart.co/send` is returning HTML

Comment: @Gabriel Christiansen What should be the endpoint in my application? Is it the ContactForm.js file or something else? My knowledge of endpoints is small. The static folder contains the html, css and js folders. Application structure in screenshot below. https://imgur.com/a/8J9iKAM

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. What are you expecting the POST to `https://delightart.co/send` to do?

Comment: @Gabriel Christiansen I used this source when creating the contact form. [link](https://w3collective.com/react-contact-form/)

Comment: You need to set up the NodeJs Server then in order to handle HTTP requests like that. If I were you, I'd have the node server be a different project than your react code. Spend some time learning about nodejs and express. Essentially you'll have a frontend project and a backend project.